# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file, when importing html file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using React.js. I want to embed an html file to show into the browser. First I import the html file. But when using the html file into `embed` tag. It throws and error saying "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file"

Here is the code -

```
import React from 'react';
import htmlFile from './htmlFile.html';

function Render(){
  return (
    <embed src = {htmlFile}>
    </embed>
  )
}

export default Render;
```

Here is the screenshot of the error -

[image]

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In a case, you can use "html-loader". to get start, install it first:

```
npm install --save-dev html-loader
```

After importing you HTML:

```
import htmlFile from './htmlFile.html';
```

You need some configs in webpack.js:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: 'html-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

For more information refer to: [html-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/#getting-started)